# Using input text instead Dropdown list as Parameter (cube as Source of data )

Tags: reporting-services

I'm setting up a parameter in SSRS as an input text, but I don't know how to link it with my Query in the data set.

I'm working with the cube as my source in my report and I created many parameters as a drop down list.

I was able to manipulate them using their dataset and change their parameter caption and value. Now I want to set another Parameter but as an input text this time!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your input parameter is for Account name.
You wish to filter your report to show only data for let's say for Account "XYZ".

Parameter Name:**ParameterAccountName**

user have input **ParameterAccountName** as "XYZ"

Now in your query you could add it something like below

```
select * from account where accountname=@ParameterAccountName
```

Here is the article which will help you more.
https://reportsyouneed.com/ssrs-tip-put-parameters-in-your-query-not-your-filter/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ank , But for my case my data source here is cube this doesnt apply with my situation , as i mention , i can work with drop down parameter but with input text it's complicated

Comment: unfortunately I am not aware of cube, but could you post your dataset query with cube. Maybe query will give more idea about how to add parameter.

Comment: SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[ORDER QTY], [Measures].[PRICE WITH DISCOUNT], [Measures].[LINE TOTAL] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([DWH REF PRODUCT].[PRODUCT ID].[PRODUCT ID].ALLMEMBERS * [DWH REF PRODUCT].[H_PRODUCT].[PRODUCT].ALLMEMBERS ) }  FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@SALESDETAILNUMBERHSALESORDERNUMBER, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM [SALES CUBE]) WHERE ( IIF( STRTOSET(@SALESDETAILNUMBERHSALESORDERNUMBER, CONSTRAINED).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@SALESDETAILNUMBERHSALESORDERNUMBER, CONSTRAINED), [SALES DETAIL NUMBER].[H_SALES_ORDER_NUMBER].currentmember ) )

Comment: that's my Query of the data set ! as you can see @SALESDETAILNUMBERHSALESORDERNUMBER is the name of my parameter

Comment: do you want your input text to be a column name i.e if user input "accountName" this is column name and not name of account.
Another ex user input"accountnr" and this is column name not value of column accountnr?

Comment: No , the input text here is the number of sales tickets ! So when i enter the number of the sale ticket in the text box , i got all the detail about that ticket number , i hope u get my example

Comment: AnkUser i found the solution how to change my dataset Query to be able to implement the inserted data :
StrTomember ('[SALES DETAIL NUMBER].[H_SALES_ORDER_NUMBER].[SALES ORDER ID].&['+@Number+']')

Comment: Cool and how did you achieved it?

Comment: i digged in the internet , actually i didn't know i should put all the sentence in string , so i was putting only ['+@Number+'] as string which was false , i should have make all the sentence as a string , Thanks for your reply btw !